# Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $a \in G$.
Suppose that $|a|=n$ and $n=mk$ for some positive integers $m$ and $k$.
What is $|a^k|$?

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $a \in G$.
Suppose that $|a|=n$ and $n=mk$ for some positive integers $m$ and $k$.
What is $|a^k|$?

**attempt:**
Let $a \in G$ such that $|a|=n$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
a^n = a^{mk} = (a^k)^m = e_G
\end{equation*}
where $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$. Thus, the order of $a^k$ is $m$.

In particularly, by theorem:
Let $(G,*)$ be a group, $a \in G$, and
$|a|=n$. Then, for all $k \in \Bbb N$,
$|a^k| = \frac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}$,
we have, $|a^k| = \frac{n}{\gcd(k,mk)} = \frac{n}{k} = m$.

Does it true? On the other hand, in the answer key says that the answer is
$\frac{n}{m}$. How to get this?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The answer key is wrong.

Comment: You are right, nice work

Comment: Great. Thanks!!!

Comment: To see why the answer key is wrong, consider the group $(\Bbb Z_7,\times)$ with $n=|5|=6$. Now $m=3$ and $k=2$ but $|5^2|=3\ne n/m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first attempt, note that what you obtained, $(a^k)^m = e$ does not guarantee that $o(a^k) = m$. It tells you that
$$o(a^k) \mid m \implies o(a^k) \le m$$

To show that  $o(a^k) = m$, we need to also show that $o(a^k) \ge m$. To show this, suppose for a contradiction that $o(a^k) < m$. Then, $\exists t \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $t < m$ and $(a^k)^t = e$. But then, we have
$(a^k)^t = a^{kt} = e$ for $kt < km$ (since $t < m$). But this means $o(a) < km = n$, contradiction.

Your second attempt is perfectly valid.

Comment: Okay got it now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. That was just a small correction (I probably wouldn't even call that a correction but maybe a more formal way) so all the work was yours to begin with. Good luck :)